# Displaying total number of products sold in frontend

Tags: product, php, ce-1.9.0.1

Hello I am trying to display the total number of products sold in magento frontend to be precise in the header section.

```
$from ='2014-07-07';
$to =date('Y-m-d',time());
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
 ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'Sample Product')->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
   echo "<pre>";
   print_R($_productCollection->getData());
   exit;
```

This is the code that I am using in the phtml file and calling it from a static block in magento admin panel however nothing is appearing.
The outcome I would like to achieve is:
             [image]

If anyone would be able to help me I can provide more information.
Thank you

Comment: Did you try using addAttributeToFilter('product_id',$productId) instead of the sku ?

Comment: Code will work correctly, are you sure your block is calling the phtml file correctly ?

Comment: This is how I'm calling the phtml file from admin  panel : {{block type="core/template" template="page/html/sold.phtml"}} and this is how I'm calling it in header.phtml <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('sold')->toHtml() ?> The outcome on the site is Array ( ) and the main content + footer disappear which means there is a problem somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code for count total sold product

```
$from ='2014-07-07';
$to = date('Y-m-d',time());
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
   echo "<pre>";
   $QtyArray = array();
  foreach($_productCollection->getData() as $_data)
  {
      $QtyArray[] = $_data['ordered_qty'];
  }
  echo 'Total Sold Products = '.array_sum($QtyArray);
```

Comment: Thank you this is the right answer , works straight away !